# How to have a stub return a specific stub if parameters match (like stub routing)?

Tags: sinon

So I've got code basically like this:

```
var myStub = sinon.stub();
myStub.withArgs(sinon.match.has("key":"value")).returns({status: "OK!"});
```

And I want to use that in a stub like this:

```
stub.WithArgs(sinon.match.has("name","Configuration)).returns(myStub(params))
```

where the arguments passed to my stub are essentially passed along to my getConfig call ONLY if there is a property called "name" with the value of "Configuration".

Where it is called like this:

```
myFunction(
{
   name: "Configuration,
   params: {
      key: "value"
   }
}
```

That make sense? What's the proper Sinon approach to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`callsFake`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.5/stubs/#stubcallsfakefakefunction):

```js
stub.withArgs(sinon.match.has("name", "Configuration")).callsFake((arg) => myStub(arg.params));
```

---

Here is a complete working `Jest` test:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

test('call stub from stub', () => {
  var myStub = sinon.stub();
  myStub.withArgs(sinon.match.has("key", "value")).returns({ status: "OK!" });

  const stub = sinon.stub();
  stub.withArgs(sinon.match.has("name", "Configuration")).callsFake((arg) => myStub(arg.params));

  const response = stub({
    name: "Configuration",
    params: {
      key: "value"
    }
  });

  expect(response).toEqual({ status: "OK!" });  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I worked on it for a while yesterday and came up with something similar that works.